# I want to plot the count of over a specific number e,g 2000

Tags: python, dataframe

```
ax = df_1['neighbourhood'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(14,8),
                                               title="Neighbourhood that showed")
ax.set_xlabel("neighboorhood")
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency")
```

Comment: Do you think anyone is going to reverse-engineer your code?

Comment: [What is your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the result of the `value_counts()` to a Series and filter it as below:

```
count = df_1['neighbourhood'].value_counts()
ax = count[count > 2000].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(14,8), title="Neighbourhood that showed")
ax.set_xlabel("neighboorhood") 
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency")
```